# Select last child with different types of children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a .page div element, with multiple children, of types header, div and footer.

My goal is to give the last of the children elements of the .page element a larger margin, but this does not do the job:

```
.page:last-child { margin-bottom:2em; }
```

Neither does this:

```
.page :last-child { margin-bottom:2em; }
```

How should I use the operator?

EDIT: An example of the HTML:

```
<div class="page">
    <header>...</header>
    <div class="container">...</div>
    <div class="grayback">...</div>
    <div class="container">...</div>
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

So I would need the second container to have the extra margin.

Comment: We need some HTML man... ;)

Comment: Sorry Mike, you're right. I added the HTML in my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
.page :last-child {
    margin-bottom:2em; 
}
```

Allows any element.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMXaw/)

Comment: But what if I would decide to add section-elements as children of the .page element, as well? Then this would not work.

Comment: Updated my original answer, the example you said you tried worked fine.

Comment: @Gerard: yes it would; though I think you'd be best off using the child combinator: `.page > :last-child`

Comment: Ah yes I see what went wrong before. What it does now is it also applies the margin to children of the .page's children, so the last child of the header element. How do I select the last-child of only the direct children of .page?

Comment: Yes @Davids suggestion stops this though.